In Mandarin can you say 我告你 to mean "I'm gonna tell on you"?
(instead of the fuller word 告發)
I ask because in Cantonese, when I was in school, I heard it quite often - I don't speak it well (it was an English-language school so I was fine) but I'm quite sure that's how they phrased it.
But I don't see it in the dictionary.

"I'm gonna tell on you" is kid talk for "I'm reporting you to a superior for your wrongdoings/misbehaviour". I have never heard "我告你" to mean "I'm gonna tell on you" in Mandarn - IMO it's used in very informal contexts (properly: "我告訴你") and literally means "I'm informing you" but in a warning tone ("I'm warning you").

Pretty sure "我要告你" is fairly common between MSM speaking kids.

In Cantonese, between common citizens, 我告你 means 我控告你 (I sue you)
Only between school kids, 我告你 means 我向老師告發你 = I'll report you to the teacher
More examples
小明告小強推他 = 小明向老師告發小強推他 = Xiao Ming reported to the teacher that Xiao Qiang pushed him
Notice: 告(report/ complain) only to the teachers, not anyone else including parents e.g. 小明向父親投訴小強推他 = Xiao Ming complained to his father that Xiao Qiang pushed him
Mandarin doesn't use 告 this way, 小明告發小強 cannot be reduced to 小明告小強

The same in Taiwan, kids there often say "我要告老師 - I am reporting (you) to the teacher".

"我要告老師 would mean "I am suing the teacher" in Hong Kong, As a school kid, you can only "告'(reporting/complaining) a fellow student

This is a pure kids' talk at a very young age, at which they haven't developed the concept of "lawsuit", and often spoken by boys, who usually have less "vocabulary" capability than the same age girls :) "我要告老師= 我要告訴老師" - I am reporting (you) to the teacher (a person of the highest authority at that time in their life)

Don't know anything about 粤语, except it sounds strange when I hear it on the news! Maybe "我告你" is acceptable in 粤语.
1 kid talking to a naughty kid: Use either 告诉 or 告状:
你太淘气了, 我去告诉你妈妈.
or
你太淘气了, 我会向你妈妈告状!

that‘s really commonly used in the North-east of China，but the attitude of this sentence is not so peaceful。If somebody say that，maybe he's angry.
